# Seeking documentation to locate an Apple iPhone or iPad from your address book contacts

Tags: ios, networking, ip-address, contacts

The 'WhatsApp' application is able to deliver - what is presumably - a TCP payload (your message) directly to the iDevice of the person you aimed it at in the WhatsApp application. The short question is: 'How does it find the current IP address of the target iDevice? I am not asking for anyone to give me chapter and verse - just point me at whatever Apple documentation explains how to do this and describes the way the various steps in the process occur (e.g. Does iOS poll active sockets asking 'does anyone want this frame?') I've been searching for this for ages and have found nothing technical other than the trivial 'how to use the app' type data. I want my app to send a UDP payload at a 'friend' from my contacts book and get a reply. That's it - nothing abnormal. At present, I don't know where to start. All constructive contributions gratefully received.

Comment: I would presume that they use push notifications. Each device supplies a unique device token that is stored in the WhatsApp servers. They can then send a message through Apple's servers that targets that token.  Each iOS device maintains a persistent connection to the Apple server, so Apple can route the message to the device, or hold it until the next time the device connects

Comment: V grateful to you for this. I'll gen up on accessing/using Apple's push services. Presumably the unique Apple device ID - or token - can be determined from the friend's telephone number and hence is available from the contacts list. Once again, many thanks.

Comment: No, when an app installs and registers for push notifications a uniquen token is generated for that app on that device. The app needs to store that token in a database somewhere along with a user id or whatever other identifier it has (in the case of WhatsApp they ask the user for their phone number).

Comment: Ahh! OK, thank you again. Push Notifications is definitely my first port of call. I'm very grateful indeed to you for this.